# Is it advisable to speed up scraping using selenium by starting multiple webdrivers?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I have over 19,000 links which I need to visit to scrape data from. Each takes about 5 seconds to fully load, which means that I will need slightly more than 26 hours to scrape everything on a single webdriver.

To me, it seems that a solution is simply to start another webdriver (or few others) in a separate python notebook which goes through another portion of the links in parallel. i.e:

In first iPython notebook:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver1 = webdriver.Firefox()
... scraping code looping over links 0-9500 using driver1...
```

In second iPython notebook:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver2 = webdriver.Firefox()
... scraping code looping over links 9501-19000 using driver2...
```

I'm fairly new to scraping so this question may be completely elementary/ridiculous(?). However, I've tried searching for this and haven't seen anything on the topic, so I would appreciate any advice on this matter. Or any recommendations for a better/more correct way to implement this.

I've heard of multi-threading using the thread module (http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_multithreading.htm), but wonder whether implementing it in this manner would have any advantage over simply creating multiple webdrivers as in the aforementioned code.

Comment: Read the answer on this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39036137/how-yo-make-a-selenium-scripts-faster

Answer (score 1):

You really need to use Selenium in order to do this?
Check [Scrapy](http://scrapy.org) with this framework you can easily send a lots of request and scrape data. Selenium is useful to get browser automation.

Comment: Thanks - I have read the book, and was advised to use Selenium because the pages I am seeking to get data from have a lot of javascript which requires processing through a client-side browser.