# Scraping Website Needing Interaction

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm working on a scraping project - looking at what recylcing companies offer for different products in the UK

I've run into a problem with this website:

http://www.musicmagpie.co.uk/entertainment/

I have a list of barcodes I want to find their buy price for (enter barcode into search box and hit 'Add button). I've managed to get a Selenium Webdriver working, but it's a very slow process and I can't run through lots of barcodes without the website crapping out at me and killing my process at some point.

I'm aiming for about 1 search per sec, at the moment it's taking be about 5+ secs on average. This is the code I'm running:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Users\leonK\Documents\Python Scripts\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get('http://www.musicmagpie.co.uk/start-selling/basket-media')

countx = 0
count = 0
for EAN in EANs:
    countx += 1
    count += 1

    if count % 200 == 0:
        driver.close()
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Users\leonK\Documents\Python Scripts\chromedriver.exe")
        driver.get('http://www.musicmagpie.co.uk/start-selling/basket-media')
        count = 1

    driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="txtBarcode"]""").send_keys(str(EAN))

    #If popup window appears, exception will close it as first click will fail.
    try:    
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="getValSmall"]""").click()
    except:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="gform_close"]""").click()

    prodnames = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("""//div[@class='col_Title']""")
    if len(prodnames) == count:
        ProductName.append(prodnames[0].text)
        BuyPrice.append(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("""//div[@class='col_Price']""")[0].text)
    else:
        ProductName.append('nan')
        BuyPrice.append('nan')
        count = len(prodnames)

    elapsed = time.clock()    
    print('MusicMagpieScraper:', EAN, '--', countx, '/', len(EANs), '--', (elapsed - start), 's')

driver.close()
```

I've got some experience using Urllib and parsing with BeautifulSoup, and would prefer to switch over to that. But, I don't know how to extract that data without the webdriver doing the clicks.

Any advice/tips would be very appriciated!

Added:

The add button link is:

```
__doPostBack('ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderDefault$mainContent$tabbedMediaVal_10$getValSmall','')
```

This is the JS function I found:

```
{name: "__EVENTTARGET", value: ""}
{name: "__EVENTARGUMENT", value: ""}
{name: "__VIEWSTATE", value: "/wEPDwUENTM4MQ9kFgJmD2QWAmYPZBYCZg9kFgJmD2QWBGYPZB…uZSAhaW1wb3J0YW50O2RkQweS+jvDtjK8er7dCKBBRwOWWuE="}
{name: "ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderDefault$signIn_8$hdn_BasketValue", value: "2"}
{name: "ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderDefault$mainContent$tabbedMediaVal_10$txtBarcode", value: "5051275026429"}
{name: "ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderDefault$mainContent$tabbedMediaVal_10$wtmBarcode_ClientState", value: ""}
{name: "ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderDefault$mainContent$tabbedTechVal_11$txtSearch", value: "Enter item (e.g. iPhone 5)"}
{name: "ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderDefault$mainContent$tabbedTechVal_11$wmSearch_ClientState", value: ""}
{name: "ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderDefault$mainContent$LegoVal_12$ddlLego", value: "-999"}
{name: "ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderDefault$mainContent$TotalValueBox_14$txtPromoVoucher_sm", value: ""}
{name: "ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderDefault$mainContent$TotalValueBox_14$txtPromoVoucher", value: ""}
{name: "__SCROLLPOSITIONX", value: "0"}
{name: "__SCROLLPOSITIONY", value: "0"}
{name: "hiddenInputToUpdateATBuffer_CommonToolkitScripts", value: "1"}
```

line 4 is where the barcode is input:

```
{name: "ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderDefault$mainContent$tabbedMediaVal_10$txtBarcode", value: "5051275026429"}
```

Hopefully useful info, I don't know where to go from here and google hasn't helped too much

Comment: go to these tutorials they will help you . https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLQVvvaa0QuDfV1MIRBOcqClP6VZXsvyZS

Comment: Sample bar code?

Comment: __doPostBack('ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderDefault$mainContent$tabbedMediaVal_10$getValSmall','')

Comment: Is this what you mean?
Watched all of that series of videos and still unsure about how I would go about this without Selenium

Comment: @Leon Kyriacou, even if anyone is willing to help you, he has to know how a barcode look like to give a shot. You have written so many stuffs except for that necessary one.

Comment: Ahh sorry, I'm being dim! 5030930092559 this is a barcode for Dead Space 2 (Xbox)

Comment: I went through your description several times to understand your need. My head is spinning. Do you want that result using selenium or using something else except for selenium? If something else then why did you pasted this selenium thing in your post?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39036137/how-yo-make-a-selenium-scripts-faster

Comment: I'm currently getting the results using selenium. I don't want use selenium and instead use something faster and more reliable (browser dies on me after a while)

Answer (score 1):

I managed to find a solution to this using requests

```
    get_response = requests.get(url='http://www.musicmagpie.co.uk/start-selling/')
    post_data = {'__EVENTTARGET' : 'ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderDefault$mainContent$tabbedMediaVal_10$getValSmall',
           '__EVENTARGUMENT' : '',
           'ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderDefault$mainContent$tabbedMediaVal_10$txtBarcode' : ean}
    # POST some form-encoded data:
    post_response = requests.post(url='http://www.musicmagpie.co.uk/start-selling/', data=post_data)    

    soup = BeautifulSoup(post_response.text, "lxml")

    BuyPrice = soup.find('div', class_='col_Price').text.rstrip()
    ProductName = soup.find('div', class_='col_Title').text.rstrip()
```

This code sends a dictionary of functions/values (may not be correct terminology!) and it fires back an easy-to-parse response from which I pulled the data I wanted!